# Showing a joint process is markov

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, markov-process, stochastic-pde

Suppose $S_t$ satisfies the equation
$$dS_t=S_t(a(X_t)dt+b(X_t)dW_t)$$

Where $X_t$ is a Markov process.Then is the joint process $(S_t,X_t)$ Markov?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joint process $\boldsymbol{Y}_t=(S_t,X_t)$ is Markov because it satisfies the two dimensional SDE $d\boldsymbol{Y}_t=\boldsymbol{\alpha}(\boldsymbol{Y}_t)\,dt+\boldsymbol{\beta}(\boldsymbol{Y}_t)\,d\boldsymbol{W}_t$ with $\boldsymbol{\alpha}(S_t,X_t)=(S_ta(X_t),\alpha_2(X_t))$ and $\boldsymbol{\beta}(S_t,X_t)=(S_tb(X_t),\beta_2(X_t))\,.$ The extra functions $\alpha_2,\beta_2$ exist because $X_t$ was Markov.

Comment: Can every Markov process be written as a solution to an SDE?

Comment: @abc : strictly speaking I don't hink so. That is, if Markov is defined as being memory less (the ususal definition). For example when $X_t$ is taken to be the Poisson process we cannot represent it as the solution to an SDE driven by a BM. For practical purposes a viable definition of "Markov" is when the process is the solution to an SDE whose coefficient functions depend only on $t$ and the process at $t$. As far as I remember there is a connection between the two but they are not strictly equivalent.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So you are assuming here that $X_t$ is Markov according to your second definition?

Comment: @abc : Exactly .